# While using useMediaQuery hook, getting error: Rendered more hooks than during previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, media-queries, react-tooltip

I am trying to hide a tooltip on mobile devices. For this, I am using `useMediaQuery` to detect the width like this:

```
const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 767px)' })
```

Then I am passing `isMobile` to a ReactTooltip component as the prop `disabled`.

```
<ReactTooltip  disable={isMobile} id="favouriteMeeting"  place="bottom" effect="solid">
    Make Favourite
</ReactTooltip>
```

But whenever I click on a meeting, I am getting this error -

> Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: This error can be caused when you have a hook wrapped in a conditional statement. Can you include the rest of the code for your component?